# Including an argument when defining an event

Tags: javascript

Let me prefix this with saying that I **never** use anonymous functions. I didn't understand asynchronous JavaScript until I stopped using anonymous functions.

With that being said (do not use anonymous functions in the answer):

Q: Is there a more direct way to write this such that function volume gets called with an argument (without first calling a function to call function volume)?

```
$(document).on('click','.glyphicon-volume-up',volumeOff)
$(document).on('click','.glyphicon-volume-off',volumeUp)
function volumeOff() {
    volume(0)
}
function volumeUp() {
    volume(1)
}

function volume(arg) {
}
```

I'd like to do something like:

```
$(document).on('click','.glyphicon-volume-up',volume(0))
$(document).on('click','.glyphicon-volume-off',volume(1))
```

without using anonymous functions.

Comment: you can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) like `$(document).on('click','.glyphicon-volume-up',volume.bind(null, 0))`

Comment: why do you hate anonymous functions so much, they have a place to be used, you should take some time and read up on where using anonymous functions in JavaScript can be very useful.

Comment: I think it took me about a year before I understood what was going on with async, and I blame anonymous functions because of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to bind a new function. You can reuse the same function with use jQuery's event data.

```js
$(document).on('click','.off', 0, volume)
$(document).on('click','.up', 1, volume)

function volume(event) {
    alert(event.data);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class=up>UP</button>
<button class=off>OFF</button>
```

Comment: I like all your revisions.

Comment: @Phillip: Thanks. I screwed it up for a minute there. You can use two functions just as well, but it may make sense to roll the logic into one.

Answer (score 2):

According to [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler) I often use the form

```
$(document).on('click', '.glyphicon-volume-up', 0, volume);
```

This way the parameter (may it be 0 or 1, or in other cases it may even be an object or whatever you like) is accessible via e.data in the event handler function. It means you can access it like

```
function volume(e) {
    var vol = e.data;
}
```

It's important though that you make the event object *e* available to your handler function with adding it to you function definition as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this one:

```
$(document).on('click','.glyphicon-volume-up',volume.bind(null, 0));
$(document).on('click','.glyphicon-volume-off',volume.bind(null, 1));
```

Above we make use of the `bind` method, which allow us to call a function providing its context, the value of `this` (which in this case doesn't matter, hence we pass null) and to pass the values for it's arguments.

Another alternative, it would be to make use of the `apply` or the `call` methods.

For a detailed explanation about the `bind` method, please have a look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`proxy` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) to specify the context and parameters for a function:

```
$(document).on('click','.glyphicon-volume-up', $.proxy(volume, this, 0));
$(document).on('click','.glyphicon-volume-off', $.proxy(volume, this, 1));
```

The `proxy` method is a browser independent replacement for the [`bind` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), as that is not supported by some older browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `data` parameter
[.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click','.glyphicon-volume-up', {value: 0}, volumeOff);
$(document).on('click','.glyphicon-volume-off', {value: 1}, volumeUp);

function volumeOff(e) {
    volume(e.data.value);
}
function volumeUp(e) {
    volume(e.data.value);
}
```

Comment: So value isn't a keyword. I can use my own word there instead of value?

Comment: In my example I'm using an object. The keys can have any value you want. In some cases you have to enclose the key in quotes. But in this case you can also pass the value directly as @squint has shown in his answer.